# Css animation tool reverse

Tags: html, css, animation, css-animations

https://codepen.io/ayeshariyaz/pen/RwWebVB?editors=1100

```
h2 span{
  animation: animate 2s alternate infinite;

}
```

Hello, I have done a quick CSS animation typography. Now I want the animation to run backward too. So the animation begins from ‘H’ of Hello World and then it should again start from ‘D’ all the way to ‘H’. And this should run on a loop.
Your help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please post the code from the CodePen here. Please read [how to create a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: I think the only way to achieve this is with Javascript